# What is this Tomcat Server startup error?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-neon

Eclipse Neon, Win 7. I added a Tomcat server 8.5 to a project.

I can go to Windows Component Services and manually start the Tomcat server, no problem.

When I try to start the server through the Eclipse project I get this message in the Eclipse Console window:

```
May 06, 2017 9:43:44 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ImpactAssessmentProject' did not find a matching property.
May 06, 2017 9:43:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.12
May 06, 2017 9:43:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Mar 8 2017 17:41:47 UTC
May 06, 2017 9:43:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.5.12.0
May 06, 2017 9:43:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
May 06, 2017 9:43:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
May 06, 2017 9:43:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
May 06, 2017 9:43:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131
May 06, 2017 9:43:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_131-b11
May 06, 2017 9:43:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
May 06, 2017 9:43:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\User\PhDCode Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
May 06, 2017 9:43:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
May 06, 2017 9:43:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\User\PhDCode Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
May 06, 2017 9:43:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
May 06, 2017 9:43:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\User\PhDCode Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
May 06, 2017 9:43:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\endorsed
May 06, 2017 9:43:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
May 06, 2017 9:43:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_131/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\iis express\PHP\v7.1;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Users\nicomp\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Progra;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\wbin;C:\Go\bin;C:\Users\nicomp\.dnx\bin;C:\Users\nicomp\AppData\Local\.meteor\;c:\user\gradle\bin\;C:\Users\nicomp\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\nicomp\eclipse\jee-neon\eclipse;;.
May 06, 2017 9:43:45 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
May 06, 2017 9:43:45 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
May 06, 2017 9:43:45 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
May 06, 2017 9:43:45 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
May 06, 2017 9:43:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 820 ms
May 06, 2017 9:43:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 06, 2017 9:43:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.12
May 06, 2017 9:43:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ImpactAssessmentProject]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ImpactAssessmentProject]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HttpServletRequest
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredMethods(Introspection.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadMethodsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:328)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5114)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HttpServletRequest
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    ... 19 more

May 06, 2017 9:43:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

May 06, 2017 9:43:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

May 06, 2017 9:43:45 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
May 06, 2017 9:43:45 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
May 06, 2017 9:43:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
May 06, 2017 9:43:45 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
May 06, 2017 9:43:45 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Comment: What happens, when you try the same thing under admin. privileges?

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný Do you mean from the Windows Services panel? I can start the Tomcat server there with no problem. If I do that, then when I try to start it from the Eclipse project I get an error that the ports are already in use and it won't start. I don't get all the errors I posted above.

Comment: Do you have multiple java machines installed? The problem could be in using different machines for invoking service.

Comment: Or Eclipse could have its own java machine in its installation folder, check it out. :)

Comment: I meant running Eclipse under admin. and trying the same thing. I am not really sure, but it could be necessary to have RW privileges to Tomcat server folder. When you are on development PC, it is not expected to have tomcat server installed. Extracted zip is enough. (These are just some ideas, which could help you the solution.)

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný I started Eclipse as admin and I got the same error.

Comment: This one is really over stupid, but have you tried restart pc? Or try uninstall your tomcat server, extract zip (https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) into folder in user space and add it in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create the Tomcat server and start it through Eclipse *without* associating the server with my project. When I associated the project, I got the error described above. 
Then I went back and fixed some configuration errors in the project so it would build, including adding the correct reference to Tomcat in the project properties / Project facets / runtimes window. That may have been residue from all the other things I changed trying to fix this problem, I don't know. 
After fixing the project so it would build, I was able to associate the project with the Tomcat server and **voila** the server started and the project executed properly. This is why we make the big dollars.